# geometry matching and update

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to match geometries from two tables and update one table based on the match. But this is taking huge time.

Table1

```
+-------------+----------+-------------+
| Column      | Type     | Modifiers   |
|-------------+----------+-------------|
| id          | bigint   |             |
| jid         | integer  |             |
| geom        | geometry |             |
+-------------+----------+-------------+
Indexes:
    "points_geom_gix" gist (geom)
    "points_jid_idx" btree (jid)
```

Table2

```
+----------+----------+------------+
| Column   | Type     | Modifiers  |
|----------+----------+------------|
| id       | integer  |            |
| geom     | geometry |            |
+----------+----------+------------+
Indexes:
    "jxn_geom_idx" gist (geom)
```

I tried with bellow queries.

```
UPDATE table1  SET jid = a.id from table2 a WHERE st_equals(geom,a.geom);
```

and

```
UPDATE table1 SET jid = b.id from table1 as a JOIN table2 b on st_equals(a.geoproperty,b.geom);
```

But both queries are taking huge amount of time(hours).

If I do count of matching geometries in both tables it will give count within seconds.

UPDATE
I am using PostgreSQL 9.5.7 and Postgis 2.2.1

Comment: Approximately how many records do you have in the tables? Do you notice update performance issues on other tables too?

Comment: What version of Postgis? Can you post explain? Does including bounding box comparison speed it up? `WHERE geom ~= a.geom AND st_equals(geom,a.geom);`

Comment: I updated the question with versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you required only bounding box level comparison use "=" on geometry columns instead of st_equals, its fast.  Like a.geom=b.geom.

Refer to this as well,

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45275267/slow-query-when-comparing-geometries)

Comment: What do you mean by bounding box level comparison?

Comment: means it will check if the bounding boxes of two compared geometries are equal or not. Also check "~=".